# How to Output chosen DIV elements that are stored in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I'm creating a card game where the user chooses 2 out of 3 cards. I then store those cards into an array and want to be able to print out the cards that were stored in the array with the actual image of the cards that the user chose.

I've tried looping through the array and then using innerHTML to push the results to a specific div but I keep getting "**[object HTMLDivElement]**". It also prints that out 3 times instead of 2 (since we are choosing 2 cards there should only be two elements to print out, I suspect the loop is running an extra time).

The below is the loop I have tried but I also am including a codepen for further clarity.

**https://codepen.io/cramos2/pen/pMVjez**

```
 var holder = document.getElementById("cardResults");
        for(var i=0; i < chosenCards.length; i++){
          holder.innerHTML += "<p>" + chosenCards[i] + "</p><br>";
    }
```

```js
let chosenCards = new Array();

class tarot {
  //constructor
  constructor(cards) {
    this.cardsArray = cards;
  }

  startReading() {
    this.shuffleCards(this.cardsArray);
    //call shuffle method
  }

  //Adds class "flipped" to the cards 
  flipCard(card, cards) {
    if (this.canFlipCard(card)) {
      if (chosenCards.length >= 2) {
        console.log("removing1");
        //from here 
        for (let card0 in cards) {
          let list = card0.classList;

          if (list) {
            if (!list.contains('visible')) {
              card0.removeEventListener('click', card0.fn);
            }
          }
        }
      } //to here
      else if (!card.classList.contains('visible')) {
        debugger;
        card.classList.add('visible');

        chosenCards.push(card);
        console.log(chosenCards);

        //this is where print out 
        var holder = document.getElementById("cardResults");
        for (var i = 0; i < chosenCards.length; i++) {
          holder.innerHTML += "<p>" + chosenCards[i] + "</p><br>";
        }
            card.removeEventListener('click', card.fn);
      }
    }
  }
  //Need a Shuffle method in here

  shuffleCards(cardsArray) {
    for (let i = cardsArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [cardsArray[i], cardsArray[randIndex]] = [cardsArray[randIndex], cardsArray[i]];
    }
    cardsArray = cardsArray.map((card, index) => {
      card.style.order = index;
    });
  }

  //gets the card
  getCardType(card) {
    return card.getElementsByClassName('card-value')[0].src;
  }
  //returns card
  canFlipCard(card) {
    return card
  }
}

//this will call the reading to start when page is loaded
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
  ready()
}

function ready() {
  //declares card's' & sets it to the card class in HTML
  let cards = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('card'));
  //creates new instance of tarot class 
  let tarotReading = new tarot(cards);
  let over = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('over'));
  over.forEach(overlay => {
    overlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
      overlay.classList.remove('visible');
      tarotReading.startReading();
    });
  });

  //flips the cards
  cards.forEach(card => {
    card.addEventListener('click', card.fn = function clicked() {
      tarotReading.flipCard(card, cards);
      //remove cards that dont have visible tag
    });
  })
  console.log(chosenCards[0]);
}
```

```css
h1 {
  color: #7B68EE;
  padding left: 50px;
  padding right: 50px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 500px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  height: 175px;
  width: 125px;
}

.card-face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.card.visible .card-back {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card.visible .card-front {
  transform: rotateY(0)
}

.card-back {
  background-color: black;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
}

.card-front {
  background-color: black;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Tarot</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-back card-face card1" id="card1">
        <p> 1
          <p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-front card-face">
        <p> The Hermit
          <p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-back card-face card2">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="card-front card-face">
        The Fool
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-back card-face card3">
        3
      </div>
      <div class="card-front card-face">
        The Empress
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="over container">Shuffle</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div id="cardResults">
  </div>
</body>
```

The expected result would be the flipped over card with the text (not the number of the card) that the user has chosen.

Comment: because you can not append an HTML element as a string. You need to rethink your solution with appendChild.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this:

```
for(var i=0; i < chosenCards.length; i++){
  holder.appendChild(chosenCards[i].cloneNode(true));
}
```

Comment: `chosenCards` is a an array of dom objects, not a strings. if you wanted to append it as a string you would have to do `p_node.innerHTML = chosenCards[i].outerHTML;` as is, your solution has the same problem as the OPs solution.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. My bad, did not look through the codepen thoroughly enough. However, it would be `p_node.innerHTML = chosenCards[i].innerText` in that case. Edited my answer. However it is not very clear what OP wants to do with chosenCards (if he wants to display the text of the card or the card itself)

Comment: no, it wouldn't. he wants to append the entire div not just the text inside of it. the outerHTML property is the string version of the element and it's contents.

Comment: @AntonBks I want to display the card itself. (the flipped card which has text not number)

Comment: But what is the purpose of the <p> tags then? In that case you can just push the item (appendChild(chosenCards[i]))?

Comment: https://codepen.io/antonbks/pen/qBWaaJp Working, however your loop is not checking for duplicates so the first card is getting added twice

Comment: @AntonBks thank you! I will add in the duplicates check